# How to inform the editor that they sent me the wrong PDF attachment?

Tags: journals, mathematics, peer-review

I received an email before three weeks which informs me that my paper is accepted for publication but some changes must be made.
(The changes are some spacing issues, or  "put more references" etc.)

In editorial management system they uploaded a PDF attachment in which I was supposed to find all the details.

*The problem is, the PDF contains corrections concerning an article which is not mine!*

At the beginning, I uploaded a revised version of the paper with comments referring to the problem, but the editors's response was:

> "Your most recent revision failed to address some of the comments on
>   the marked up version of the document I sent you.  These minor items
>   should be fixed..."
>
> "For example, some of the things that appeared in the previous
>   revision and were not changed include :page 1;line 7; ..."
>
> "I don't want to repeat the work that I did previously.  You still
>   have access to the file.  Upon submission of a revised manuscript,
>   please include the LaTeX source..."

Which means that the editor did not even see my comments.
The next day I sent another mail  explaining the problem but I did not receive an answer.
After 5 days I sent another mail to the editor's personal account.
(But, no response again)
My revision is due by 2016.08.12.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to email an administrative contact in or outside the system. Keep trying. DO NOT include a revised version of your paper since that seems to have confused them. Let them know that you received a revision request for a different paper entitled "Whatever the other paper is called" by X and Y and Z, and that you'd like to see if you can get the required revisions request for your paper entitled "Whatever your paper is called" by A and B and C so that you can make the corrections. Even if you already have done them, try not to be confusing by resending the corrections to your paper.

I had an editor send me a PDF of required revisions once with the file named X.pdf. When I contacted him, he was very embarrassed because he had broken the blinding by admitting that X had submitted a paper that was under revision at the journal. Keep trying. Eventually they'll understand.